# how to check github vulnerability without having admin access?

Tags: angularjs, github, dependency-graph

There is one open source github AngularJs project. As we know github automatically detects vulnerability in dependencies listed in packages.json or any other dependency file.

It has some vulnerabilities with some of its packages which are as below:

- jquery ~> 3.0.0
- moment ~> 2.19.3
- mustache ~> 2.2.1

The problem is : I do not have admin access. So even if I try to fix this issue, I won't be able to know whether my solution is working or not.

Could someone know any workaround when we can know which package listed in package.json has vulnerability without having admin access?

Comment: pull that and run in local environment.

Comment: how to see vulnerability then?